# Как отодвинуть элементы в конец дива? bootstrap5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap5

```
        <div class="row align-items-center field-separator">
            <div class="col-auto">
                <p class="mb-0">Триггеры:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto p-0">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm">Добавить триггер</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto p-0 me-3">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm">Группу</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto p-1">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" placeholder="" style="width: 50px; height: 31px;"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto p-0">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" placeholder="" style="width: 50px; height: 31px;"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Мне нужно чтобы все элементы кроме p были в конце дива. Добавление d-flex justify-content-end

UPD:

```
    <div class="row align-items-center field-separator">
        <div class="col-auto">
            <p class="mb-0">Триггеры:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">             
            <div class="col-auto p-0">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm">Добавить триггер</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto p-0 me-3">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm">Группу</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto p-1">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" placeholder="" style="width: 50px; height: 31px;"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto p-0">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" placeholder="" style="width: 50px; height: 31px;"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

сделал так но теперь все такое [image: введите сюда описание изображения]